# Difference between current_resource and new resource in opscode chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

What is the purpose of current_resource and new_resource in opscode chef. Where exactly to use them in libraries. Difference between them.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the context of a provider, `new_resource` is the actual resource object from the recipe meaning it contains the desired state of whatever the resource is describing. `current_resource` is populated from `load_current_resource` and generally contains the current state of the thing on the current system, such as the current installed version of a package or current contents of a file.

Comment: same is true in newer custom resources?  where current_resource is populated by `load_current_value` ?